# Should I change Start Menu Link names for Windows 8?

Tags: menu, windows-8

In Windows 8 Microsoft has removed the Start Menu so you can't see easily see the installed programs pieces that can be clicked on to run.  Is this correct?

So it appears when you install a program under Windows 8 that you must now just know a few letters in the start link names for what was installed, so you can then type the Windows key and those few letters to then be shown start icons for the programming.  correct?

So it appears my software menu shortcuts need to include a common two letters in each of their start menu link names so the user then can press the Windows key and type those two letters to see the software start links that have been installed.  Right idea?

Comment: Not sure of what you mean with the question. Can you explain yourself a Little bit more, please?

Comment: Not necessary. Users can switch to the "all programs" view to browse.

Answer (score 0):

> "In Windows 8 Microsoft has removed the Start Menu so you can't see
>   easily see the installed programs pieces that can be clicked on to
>   run. Is this correct?"

The Start Menu has been "reimagined" into the new Start Menu with tiles that can receive live updates.  Instead of a Start Menu that lists each program's static name, each application now has a tile which can surface fresh information relevant to the app (for example, a Weather app can show the current temperature in your city and sunny vs. cloudy graphic, etc.).

> "So it appears when you install a program under Windows 8 that you
>   must now just know a few letters in the start link names for what was
>   installed, so you can then type the Windows key and those few letters
>   to then be shown start icons for the programming. correct?"

When you type the Windows key, that brings you to the new Start Menu.  When you then type those few letters, that is automatically invoking Search (which you can also invoke at any time though Windows key + Q).

> "So it appears my software menu shortcuts need to include a common two
>   letters in each of their start menu link names so the user then can
>   press the Windows key and type those two letters to see the software
>   start links that have been installed. Right idea?"

Since it is invoking search, you don't really need a common two letters.  Just name your app something memorable that makes sense with the app's functionality, and the user can type the name of your app or its first few letters to bring it up as you describe using search.

The user can also browse through the Start Menu to find your app, and group similar applications together on the Start Menu to make apps easier to find (here is how-to info on [making and naming groups](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zxue/archive/2012/03/07/win8-howto-10-customize-metro-ui-app-tiles-and-groups.aspx)).